# Extract html sourcecode from a javascript generated output

Tags: javascript, html, beautifulsoup, text-extraction

I am currently working on a project of finding empty classrooms in our school in real time. For that purpose, I need to extract substitution published on our school page (https://ssnovohradska.edupage.org/substitution/?), since there might be any additional changes.

But when I try to extract the html source code and parse it with bs4, it cannot find the divs(class: "section print-nobreak") that contain the substitution text. When I took a look at the page source code(Ctrl+U) I found that there is only a javascript that prints it all directly.

Is there any way to extract the html after the javascript output has been already rendered?

Thanks for help!

Comment: P.S. when you go to the page, you need to switch to tomorrow's date ("Po 24.2.") in the top nav.

Answer (score 0):

Parsing HTML is unfortunately necessary to solve your problem. But I will explain how to find ways to avoid that in your future projects (not based on this website).

1. You've correctly noticed that the text is created by JavaScript code running on the page. This could also indicate that the data is either loaded from another resource (XHR/fetch call getting a response from an API) or is stored as a JSON/JS inside of the website's code. (Or is generated from an algorithm, but this is unlikely to be the case in such websites.)
2. The website actually uses both methods (initial render gets data stored inside of the website's code, but when you switch dates on the calendar it makes AJAX requests). You can see this by searching for `ReactDOM.render(React.createElement(` in the code. They're providing a HTML string to the createElement call, so I would suggest looking into the AJAX way of doing things.
3. Now, to check where the resource is located, all you need to do is opening Developer Tools in your favorite browser (usually Control+Shift+I) and navigating to the Network tab. Now that your network tab is open, you need to cause the website to load external data, for example, by pressing a date on the "calendar bar".
4. Here you will notice many external requests, but we're actually looking only for XHR calls. Click on the XHR button next to the "Filter" text field. That should result in only one request being shown:

[image: Request]

5. Unfortunately for us, the response only contains HTML. Also, API calls are protected - they require a PHP session ID and some sort of a token (`__gsh`) to not fail. So, going back to step 1 - seems like our only solution is to use regular expressions to find the text between `"report_html":"<div class` and `</div></div></div>` from the source code, if you're interested in today's date only. If you want to get contents for tomorrow or any other date - you will need to either fetch the page, save the cookies and find the token to supply to the request and then make that request, or use something like [puppeteer](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer) or [pyppeteer](https://github.com/miyakogi/pyppeteer) (since you've mentioned BS4) and load the webpage in that. If you aren't doing the data fetching that often, you should be fine overall.